# How to have similar cassandra.yaml across cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I want to configure a cassandra cluster and i want that the cassandra.yaml configuration file will be the same cross the nodes. the problem is that the listen_address has to be different on each node. As this is a yaml file, is it possible to include another yaml file? so that the main cassandra.yaml is the same and just the listen_address.yaml will differ across the cluster.

I'm not sure of the yaml syntax, but i know it can include files - will the cassandra use it?

[SNIP]
...

listen_address: !include listen_address.yaml
...

the above did not work for me. is it possible at all for cassandra?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to have includes in yaml file directly, but nothing prevents you from using Ansible/Puppet/Chef, or any other framework to process template of `cassandra.yaml` file, and substitute variables to generate real `cassandra.yaml`.

Comment: Thanks. Being a dinosaurus, I have to admit that I hate ansible and the like. I'm a humble bash/sed/awk kind of person... i do hope cassandra guys will do the effort of supporting includes as 90% of the file is similar on nodes.

Answer (score 1):

To Alex's point, you'll find this to be quite a bit easier with an actual deployment framework.

Before we implemented ours, I used to deploy with a simple Bash script.  Essentially, the same yaml (and other config files) was distributed around to each node (via SCP).  I had pre-edited the files with constants set for the properties that needed to change:

```
#cassandra.yaml
listen_address: INTERNALIP
broadcast_address: EXTERNALIP
rpc_address: INTERNALIP
broadcast_rpc_address: EXTERNALIP

#cassandra-rackdc.properties
dc=DATACENTER
rack=AZONE
```

Then I ran my Bash script that replaced the unique parts with a `sed`-based regex, like this:

```
INTERNALTP=$1
EXTERNALIP=$2
DATACENTER=$3
AZONE=$4

#set listen_address to internal IP
sed -i "s/INTERNALIP/$INTERNALIP/g" $CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra.yaml

#set broadcast_rpc_address to external IP
sed -i "s/EXTERNALIP/$EXTERNALIP/g" $CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra.yaml

#set AZONE and DATACENTER in rackdc properties
sed -i "s/DATACENTER/$DATACENTER/" $CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra-rackdc.properties
sed -i "s/AZONE/$AZONE/" $CASSANDRA_HOME/conf/cassandra-rackdc.properties
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing somwthing similar, but I really wanted to use includes. can we add a TODO to the cassandra guys?

Comment: Feel free to open JIRA for it